# React read more button

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I retrieve data from `https://api.themoviedb.org/3` API.

When I get title of each movie I would like to have a **`Read More`** button after truncate the text but I'm struggling to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import './Row.css'

// Append in order to retrive images
const base_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/';

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setMovies(request.data.results);
            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchUrl]);

    console.log(movies);

    function truncate(str, n) {
        return str?.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : str;
    }


    return (
        <div className='row'>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <div className='row__posters'>

                {movies.map((movie) => (
                    <div className='bic'>
                        <img
                            key={movie.id}
                            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
                            src={`${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`}
                            alt={movie.name}

                        />
                        <p>{movie.original_title || movie.name}</p>
                        <span>Rating: {movie.vote_average}</span>
                        <p>Polularity: {movie.popularity}</p>
                        <p className='desc'>{truncate(movie.overview, 350)}</p>

                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first move your single movie in a different component, and the using the component internal state toggle an expanded variable that will tell you if to show the entire movie overview or the truncated part

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from './axios';
    import './Row.css'

    // Append in order to retrive images
    const base_url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/';


    function truncate(str, n) {
        return str?.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : str;
    }

    const Movie = ({ movie }) => {
      const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

      return(
        <div className='bic'>
            <img
                key={movie.id}
                className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
                src={`${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path}`}
                alt={movie.name}

            />
            <p>{movie.original_title || movie.name}</p>
            <span>Rating: {movie.vote_average}</span>
            <p>Polularity: {movie.popularity}</p>
            <p className='desc'>{expanded ? movie.overview : truncate(movie.overview, 350)}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>Read more</button>
        </div>
      )
    }

    function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
        const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
                setMovies(request.data.results);
                return request;
            }
            fetchData();
        }, [fetchUrl]);

        console.log(movies);

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <div className='row__posters'>

                    {movies.map((movie) => (
                        <Movie movie={movie} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }

    export default Row;
```

Comment: Ciao @Giovanni  thanks for your answer, not sure if I get this wrong but I get big fat error saying  'movies is not defined' like this.

Comment: Ciao @FabioTorti
the only place I see the variable movies is inside the Row component, check if your fetchData is fetching correctly and passing data in the setMovies, also as an additional check in your map do this 
{movies && movies.map(...)}

Comment: @FabioTorti I changed the code, I forgot to pass the movie prop to the new Movie component, probably you were getting an error for that "movie is undefined" (not movies)

Comment: Grazie Maestro : )  now is working. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the JavaScript `string.prototype.substring(positionA, positionB)` method.

```
<p className='desc'>
    {movie.overview.substring(0, 350)}
    <a href="someLink">Read more ...</a>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your input, I can't find the way to use a redirect link as the data coming from an Api array.

Comment: @FabioTorti What would you like to happen when you press *Read more*?

Comment: I would like to get the entire movie description which is truncate to 150 characters right now. Basically I rendered bunch of data from the Api and  movie.overview is actually the movie description which I truncated, so when the user click on Read More it should get the entire description .thanks

Comment: @FabioTorti I would suggest toggling a css class on clicking read more which hides with read more /shows the extra text. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Thanks @koder613 the solution provided by giovanni is working now :) thanks a lot for your help :)